# Top 3 values per group query MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

im new to MS access, and im trying to make a query that will pull up the top 3 people in 3 different categories in terms of points, i.e the desired outcome is :

```
Child's name | Membership Type | Total Points
=============================================
Jon Snow     | Senior          | 12
Hodor        | Senior          | 13
Bran Stark   | Senior          | 67
Cersei       | Intermediate    | 14
Joffery      | Intermediate    | 19
Ramsay Bolton| Intermediate    | 25
Wun-Wun      | Junior          | 14
Arya Stark   | Junior          | 64
Ned Stark    | Junior          | 125
```

Ive found bits of code like this, which i /think/ does it,

```
SELECT StudentID, TestID, TestScore
FROM MyTable t
WHERE TestID IN
(
SELECT TOP 3 TestID 
FROM MyTable
WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID 
ORDER BY TestScore DESC, TestID
)
ORDER BY StudentID, TestScore DESC, TestID;
```

But i have no idea what this means, let alone how to adapt it to fit my needs. 
Does anyone out there have an idea on how to get the desired out come?

EDIT:  subbed in version that pulls up a syntax error.

```
SELECT [Members.Childs Name], [Members.Membership Type], [Results.Total Points]
FROM 
(SELECT [Members.Childs Name], [Members.Membership Type], [Results.Total Points],
        (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Results], [Members] sub
         WHERE sub.Total Points <= Results.Total Points
         AND sub.Membership Type = Members.Membership Type)  As GroupRank
FROM Members, Results t) As main
WHERE main.GroupRank <= 3
ORDER BY [main.Membership Type],[main.Total Points DESC]
```

P.S Unrelated, but The finale was amazing :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a correlated sub query that calculates an ordinal rank count which you can then use as a derived table to select top three:

```
SELECT main.StudentID, main.MembershipType, main.TestScore
FROM 
    (SELECT t.StudentID, t.MembershipType, t.TestScore,
            (SELECT Count(*) FROM MyTable sub 
             WHERE sub.TestScore >= t.TestScore
             AND sub.MembershipType = t.MembershipType) As GroupRank
     FROM MyTable t) As main
WHERE main.GroupRank <= 3
ORDER BY main.MembershipType, main.TestScore DESC
```

To explain specifically, *GroupRank* is calculated from a subquery (nested select in column section) that ranks *TestScores* for each *MembershipType* of outer query. However, this is not enough as you will want to use this calculated *GroupRank* to pick top three. So nest entire query inside a `FROM` clause which is known as a derived table as you created an implicit table to return another resultset. This final resultset filters for top 3 and then orders *TestScores* for each *Membership*.

In MS Access, you can save entire `FROM` clause query as its own stored query and then use that query to filter for top three:

```
SELECT g.StudentID, g.MembershipType, g.TestScore
FROM GroupRankQuery g    
WHERE g.GroupRank <= 3
ORDER BY g.MembershipType, g.TestScore DESC
```

For multiple tables, use table aliases to help which temporarily renames table sources for easier referencing:

```
SELECT main.[Childs Name], main.[Membership Type], main.[Total Points] 
FROM 
   (SELECT m.[Childs Name], m.[Membership Type], r.[Total Points], 
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Results] subR 
            INNER JOIN [Members] subM ON subR.StudentID = subM.StudentID
            WHERE subR.[Total Points] >= r.[Total Points] 
            AND subM.[Membership Type] = m.[Membership Type]) As GroupRank 
    FROM Results r
    INNER JOIN Members m ON r.StudentID = m.StudentID) As main 
WHERE main.GroupRank <= 3 
ORDER BY main.[Membership Type], main.[Total Points] DESC
```

Comment: uhhhhh. what? i'm sorry i have no idea what any of that means, like i said, i'm new i started using it like a week ago.

Comment: See further explanation. But do note StackOverflow is not a tutorial service. Consider looking into an SQL tutorial.

Comment: I tried to sub in the correct field names, and tables ( the data comes from multiple tables), and i get a syntax error from the select expression. (p.s am using access 2016)

Comment: Any field names with spaces like *Membership Type* must be enclosed in square brackets. Also, use an `INNER JOIN` between Members and Results tables using their shared id. As stands, you return a cross join of all possible combinations between both tables.

Comment: See edit with version for multiple tables, assuming *StudentID* is join key between tables.