# Order Union Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

So i have this sql:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType,  Results.TotalPoints
FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Senior"))
ORDER BY Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints
UNION
SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints
FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Intermediate"))
ORDER BY Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints
UNION
SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints
FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Junior"))
ORDER BY Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints;
```

Which gives me the desired outcome, except it is ordered alphabetically. is the a way to customise the order of the out, so in stead of:

```
ChildsName | MembershipType | TotalPoints
=========================================
Jon Snow   | Intermediate   | 48
HODOR      | Intermediate   | 67
Cersei     | Intermediate   | 789
Ned Stark  | Junior         | 5
Daenerys   | Junior         | 16
Bran Stark | Junior         | 456
Arya Stark | Senior         | 15
Rob Stark  | Senior         | 69
Tyrion     | Senior         | 6215
```

it will display:

```
ChildsName | MembershipType | TotalPoints
=========================================
Arya Stark | Senior         | 15
Rob Stark  | Senior         | 69
Tyrion     | Senior         | 6215
Jon Snow   | Intermediate   | 48
HODOR      | Intermediate   | 67
Cersei     | Intermediate   | 789
Ned Stark  | Junior         | 5
Daenerys   | Junior         | 16
Bran Stark | Junior         | 456
```

How can i do this with the code above?

Comment: Awwww! Earlier related question with [correlated subquery to pick top 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155751/top-3-values-per-group-query-ms-access) didn't work?

Comment: Nah xD so i just combined a few queries together and got it to work, but now i just want the outcome to be sorted

Comment: But I assure you it works. Just tested it. Simply, make sure column names are correct and switch the less than equal to greater than equal (for ties, adjust remove equal). Please re-consider. It scales better than this union query version as a DRYer solution (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrapped the result in a subquery to order. and for grouping and ordering by `membershipType` I have set rank for each membership type. 
I hope this will help:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName AS ChildsName, Members.MembershipType AS MembershipType,  Results.TotalPoints AS TotalPoints, 1 AS rank
    FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
    WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Senior"))
    ORDER BY Results.TotalPoints

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName AS ChildsName, Members.MembershipType AS MembershipType,  Results.TotalPoints AS TotalPoints, 2 AS rank
    FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
    WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Intermediate"))
    ORDER BY Results.TotalPoints

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName AS ChildsName, Members.MembershipType AS MembershipType,  Results.TotalPoints AS TotalPoints, 3 AS rank
    FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
    WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Junior"))
    ORDER BY Results.TotalPoints
) m
ORDER BY m.rank, m.ChildsName, m.TotalPoints;
```

Comment: ms access, but i removed the m.*, and replaced it with * FROM and it works, other than the fact that it doesnt bring up the top 3 from each category. do you have any idea what causes this?

Comment: yeah i got that... because we have removed inner ordering so it is not considering `TotalPoints` for choosing top 3.. give me a sec will edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType,  Results.TotalPoints, 0 AS MembershipTypeOrder
    FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
    WHERE Members.MembershipType='Senior'
    ORDER BY Results.TotalPoints
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints, 1 AS MembershipTypeOrder
    FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
    WHERE Members.MembershipType)='Intermediate'
    ORDER BY Results.TotalPoints
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints, 2 AS MembershipTypeOrder
    FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.[Member ID] = Results.ID
    WHERE Members.MembershipType='Junior'
    ORDER BY Results.TotalPoints
) ResultSet
ORDER BY ResultSet.MembershipTypeOrder, ResultSet.TotalPoints;
```

Alternatively, you can store the membership types in a separate table. For example:

```
MembershipTypeID | Name           | Order
=========================================
1                | Intermediate   | 1
2                | Junior         | 2
3                | Senior         | 0
```

Then, you can use an INNER JOIN to get the membership type name as well as the list order.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From (SELECT TOP 3
Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType,
Results.TotalPoints FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.
[Member ID] = Results.ID 
WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Senior")) 
ORDER BY Members.MembershipType,
Results.TotalPoints 
UNION SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName, Members.MembershipType,
Results.TotalPoints FROM Members 
INNER JOIN Results ON Members.
[Member ID] = Results.ID WHERE
(((Members.MembershipType)="Intermediate")) ORDER BY Members.MembershipType,
Results.TotalPoints UNION SELECT TOP 3 Members.ChildsName,
Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints FROM Members INNER JOIN Results ON Members.
[Member ID] = Results.ID WHERE (((Members.MembershipType)="Junior")) ORDER BY
Members.MembershipType, Results.TotalPoints) 
as myQuery order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: Sorry for the identation, I'm using the android app so is difficult for me give a correct identation

Comment: Is there anyway to put intermediate in the center of the table? All that's done is flip it upside down, sorting it descending alphabetically, what i want is to have it go : "Senior, Intermediate, Junior". but thanks for the fast reply

Comment: As well as this, it changes the order of the points, which is what i want to be in a 1st 2nd 3rd order, grouped by the membershiptype

Comment: Mmm have you tried with "UNION ALL" instead of "UNION"?

Comment: Just tried it, and that fixes the order of the points within each group, but it doesnt change the order of the groups.